# Single bulb pendant to 4 bulb pendant

Tags: replacement, bulb, cables

I am replacing a basic single bulb pendant light with a 4 bulb fitting.  There are 4 white cables coming from the new light fitting. Do i bundle them together?

Comment: How is the old light fixture wired?  New one probably will have the same connections, but with more wires.

Comment: How about a picture.

Comment: Just four white wires would be odd.  Are there any other wires coming from the fixture?

Comment: @crip659 agreed, there should also be 4 black wires.

Comment: 4 white cables I would believe, but not wires, please add a photo of the fixture showing the wires.  if the lamp sockets are now screw-in sockets that would be useful to know too.